# Angular 4 Http Request Giving error unsupport Grant Type, using web API Owin Jwt token

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, jwt, owin, angular-services

I am trying to post request to get Auth token and angular 4 keeps giving me error as

[image]

> Bad Request 400, Unsupported_Grant_Type

Following is my code :

```
let option: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    option.headers = new Headers();
    option.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //option.headers.append('access-control-allow-origin','*');

    option.body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password, grant_type: 'password' }));
    option.method = RequestMethod.Post;
   return  this.http.request("http://localhost:4200/oauth/token", option).map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        } 
    });
```

and by using Post Request this is the code :

```
 let option: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    option.headers = new Headers();
    option.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    option.method = RequestMethod.Post;
   return this.http.post('/oauth/token', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password, grant_type: "password" }), option)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
```

But in Post man tool it works fine :

[image]

here is the network details from Chrome

```
 POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 65
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fhome
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Form Data :

```
{"username":"shan","password":"ShanAli!","grant_type":"password"}
```

**My WEB APP is on PORT 4200**

here are the details for C# :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app);
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);

        // ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT should be set to 'Development'
        if (env != null && env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseErrorPage(ErrorPageOptions.ShowAll);
        }

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureWebApi(config);
        // Swagger
        SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
        // Register routes
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
        // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
        // to be Autofac.
        var erpAssembly = Assembly.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErpAdapter"]);

        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(erpAssembly);
        builder.RegisterType<ErpAdapterFactory>().As<IErpAdapterFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var diResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = diResolver;

        // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);

        app.UseWebApi(config);


    }
    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost:40909")
        };

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var issuer = "http://localhost:40909";
        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }

    private void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
       // config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post what the request's **URL**, **Method**, **Header** and **Payload** from the networks tab are after you send the request? Something is probably wrong there.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json` ?

Comment: I have pasted the details , kindly have a look

Comment: yes i have tried with application/json also , same error.

Comment: `this.http.post('/oauth/token'...` is not a valid url. Is it still broken if you put in the valid url? Also remove the `option.method` above it.

Comment: i have tried this but didnt work either. i have updated the C# code , may it is affecting from back end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is incomplete.

In your JavaScript code I don't see where you set the Authorization Basic header.

In your back end code you have code which talks about an AudienceID and Secret but then you pass a username and password in the body of the request.

Also in your backend code, I don't see the part where you look at the request and actually check the correct AudienceID and Secret was passed.

What's in the CustomOAuthProviderclass?

Several years ago I wrote a detailed article on this subject which takes you through all the steps required to implement a fully working OAuth2 system using Owin and JWT. Please have a read and let me know if you have any further questions: https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/

It should answer all your questions and as long as you build the requests correctly in JavaScript, everything will work.

One extra note from me, be very careful with allowing insecure http. You do not want to go live with that set to true. Everything should be over https because then your headers and post body will be encrypted. Otherwise they will be exposed and anyone can basically steal your id and secret and then keep issuing valid tokens. So, https all the way.